# next.js multiple configurations on next.config.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-i18next

i'm having issues with my next.js config file when trying to configure the next-i18next package (version 6) and also have a webpack config for audio, and a plugin for images. until the upgrade everything was fine, but now is not loading the defaultLanguage which i set.

my next.config.js looks like this:

```
const withImages = require('next-images');

const { nextI18NextRewrites } = require('next-i18next/rewrites');
const localeSubpaths = { en: 'en' };

module.exports = withImages({
 webpack(config, options) {
   const { isServer } = options;
   config.module.rules.push({
     test: /\.(ogg|mp3|wav|mpe?g)$/i,
     exclude: config.exclude,
     use: [
       {
         loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
         options: {
           limit: config.inlineImageLimit,
           fallback: require.resolve('file-loader'),
           publicPath: `${config.assetPrefix}/_next/static/images/`,
           outputPath: `${isServer ? '../' : ''}static/images/`,
           name: '[name]-[hash].[ext]',
           esModule: config.esModule || false,
         },
       },
     ],
   });

   return config;
 },
 rewrites: async () => nextI18NextRewrites(localeSubpaths),
 publicRuntimeConfig: {
   localeSubpaths,
 },
});
```

any help would be appreciated.